# CakePHP validation alpha problem w/ validation is checked - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, cakephp

Excuse my ignorance on this question, but what seems to be an obvious fix is not coming together for me..

My validation is working perfectly fine with the exception of when I enter any alpha characters in my form field, I get a sql error:

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'abcde' in 'where clause'...
```

As you can see I entered 'abcd' as a test..

But if I enter a numeric character and per my validation its all fine.. It appears the alpha value is being read as a column name??

**Here is my validation rule:**

```
        ...'Age' => array(
        array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 3),
        array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Age must be numeric.'
        ),
    ),
```

**Here is my controller validation code:**

```
        if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        if ($this->Plan->validates()) {
            $this->Plan->set($this->data);
            $errors = $this->Plan->invalidFields();
            $this->set('errors', $errors);
        } else {
            $this->Plan->set($this->data);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am returning my errors to my view, and the correct error "Age must be numeric." does in fact display as expected, but just with the SQL error stuff.

Thanks for any insight as to why this is happening.

Comment: When `validates()` returns true, you set `$errors`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: is it possible you just missed a bracket there?

Comment: No brackets missed that I can see.

Comment: Validation is working perfectly fine with the exception of alpha characters being entered into the fields - that just screws up the SQL for some reason...

Comment: Do you have to name the rules?  e.g. 'Age' => array( 'ruleName' => array(), 'ruleName2' => array() ).  I can't be sure but your validation rule looks strangely nested to me, either way.

Answer (score 2):

Do you even read the manual? It's clearly stated in the CookBook that you need to give your rules names if you want to use multiple rules.

Also, your array is nested completely wrong. I don't know how this could be working, but anyway, this is how your validate should look like:

```
var $validate = array(
    'Age' => array(
        'length' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 3)
        ),
        'numbers' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Age must be numeric.'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Tim, yes I've been through the manual many times. After a while these arrays start to all look the same! I see what you mean on the array structure and thanks for your tip. I am going to modify mine and run further tests.